# Add Unique Index to Existing Laravel 8 Migration Table When Duplicates In Database Exist

Tags: php, laravel

My Laravel 8 Project has a table that has many duplicates in the database.  I want to add `unique` to the table but I'm getting migration error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Non-Haz Waste' for key 'streams.streams_stream_name_unique' (SQL: alter table 'streams' add unique 'streams_stream_name_unique'('stream_name'))`.  The error is because of the existing duplicates.

Below is my migration file to add `unique` which produces the error.  Is there way to still add `unique` to my table?  If not, I also placed my `create` function that does validate and show an on-screen error that the name exists, but it creates it in the database anyway.

I'd prefer the `unique` to be part of the index, but would settle for my `addStream` function not adding the duplicate.

**2021_11_03_163710_add_unique_to_streams.php**

```
...
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('streams', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unique('stream_name', 'streams_stream_name_unique');
        });
    }
...
```

**edit.php**

```
public function addStream($id) {
    ...
    $validatedData = Validator::make(
       ['stream_name' => $this->stream_name],
       ['stream_name' => 'required|unique:streams'],
       ['required' => 'Stream Name is Required'],
    )->validate();
    
    $stream = Stream::create([
       'stream_name' => ucwords($this->stream_name)
    ]);
    ...
```

Comment: Fix (update or remove) the duplicate(s), then add the `unique` index?

Comment: Your database won't allow you to add a unique index to a table column with duplicate values. You either do not apply the unique index or you find a way to remove the duplicates from the column

Comment: The database is too big with too many duplicates. Plus, the `Streams` have relationships with other models.

Comment: Hmm, it's true I don't know the size/structure of the database, but I would think you can write a script to check for duplicates, and consolidate them in some form (map entities from the duplicate(s) to the first one found, i.e. update `stream_id` of those related records), then run the migration to add the unique index. Relying on a `unique` validation _can_ work, but it's not reliable. Additionally, if you ever need to query against `streams` by name (or alias, slug, etc), you might run into issues.

Comment: @TimLewis This would be the best way to go for sure.  As a stop gap, what would you suggest with my `addStream` function.  Any code to add to keep the `create` method from running if validation fails?

Comment: Yeah, the way you have it is close, but drop the `->validate();` and add an `if()` statement, like `if ($validatedData->fails()) { // Do something to let the user know the create fails due to a new duplicate }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, though it will likely take awhile for a large table:

```
...
public function up()
{
    DB::unprepared("
        CREATE TABLE tmp_streams SELECT * FROM streams;
        TRUNCATE TABLE streams;
        ALTER TABLE streams ADD UNIQUE INDEX streams_stream_name_unique(stream_name);
        INSERT IGNORE INTO streams SELECT * from tmp_streams;
        DROP TABLE tmp_streams;
    ");
}
...
```

If you care which fields or rows are kept, you can rewrite the INSERT with an ordered SELECT and/or ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

If you happen to be using a version of MySQL before 5.7 and don't care which row is kept, it's even simpler:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE streams ADD UNIQUE INDEX streams_stream_name_unique(stream_name);
```

Per the [ALTER TABLE Syntax doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html):

> IGNORE is a MySQL extension to standard SQL. It controls how ALTER TABLE works if there are duplicates on unique keys in the new table or if warnings occur when strict mode is enabled. If IGNORE is not specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors occur. If IGNORE is specified, only one row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted. Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable value.
>
> As of MySQL 5.6.17, the IGNORE clause is deprecated and its use generates a warning. IGNORE is removed in MySQL 5.7.